# How to query to table to get latest data from DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have DynamoDB table and I want to take only currently data uploaded in Amazon DynamoDB for manipulation purpose. I read docs from Amazon but not get to solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by current data? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

To receive a notification when data has been added/modified/deleted in Amazon DynamoDB, use **DynamoDB Streams**.

See: [Capturing Table Activity with DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)

Comment: Can we do it through Node.js

Comment: DynamoDB streams can trigger an AWS Lambda function, which can be written in Node.js. See: [AWS Lambda Walkthrough 3: Processing Events from DynamoDB Streams Using the AWS CLI (DynamoDB Streams | Node.js)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/wt-ddb.html)